# Regex: Match a string between two tags in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regexp. I am struck in writing regexp for below scenario. Can some one please help me in solving this?

If i have a String like the following:

```
<Tag1 attr="test"/>
<Tag2>
    <Tag4 attr="test"/>
    <Tag5 attr="test"/>
</Tag2>
<Tag3 attr="test"/>
```

Whats the regex to match 'test' between the <Tag2> and </Tag2> tags?

Output should match 'test' in both Tag4 and Tag5...

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: I believe this is the canonical answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You can't use regex to parse HTML/XML. Try using an HTML or XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a regex for this? I am not familiar with the Java libraries, but I would imagine there is a library that would allow you to do XQueries using XPaths. That would be the simpler approach.

[Here is a website that shows examples](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml)

[Here is a SO question on XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: +1 for XPath, but pay attention that he has a *string* and it is not a valid xml, 'cause it has no root.

Comment: it would probably be easier to throw it into a bogus root and use xpath

Comment: @user12345613 That is exactly what I was about to respond with. Why overcomplicate anything. It isn't hard to add a top-level root to any XML :)

Comment: You are right. I am trying to fix an issue in one of our projects. That project is using regexp everywhere. I have fix this using regexp. I am left with no choice.Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

XPath is really more appropriate for this.  This looks like duplicate post.  [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811001/1440715)

Perl has a couple of good xpath parsers on CPAN.  But here's a good page on [multiline regex](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/) parsing if you absolutely must use it.

Comment: Guess I was a little late here

Answer (score 0):

All said before is totally true - however if you still want to practice some regex heres an alternative:
Doing it in one match is not possible since one of the inner groups will always be discarded [(see this)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) , so you'll have to extract the inner passage first.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTagParse {

static String html = "<Tag1 attr=\"test\"/><Tag2>    <Tag4 attr=\"test_one\"/>    <Tag5 attr=\"test_two\"/></Tag2><Tag3 attr=\"test\"/>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher mat1 = Pattern.compile("Tag2>(.*)</Tag2").matcher(html);
    mat1.find();

    Matcher mat2 = Pattern.compile("<[^<>]*attr=\"([^\"]+)\"[^<>]>").matcher(mat1.group(1));
    while(mat2.find()){
        System.out.println(mat2.group(1));
    }
}

}
```

anyways, you'd be much better off using XPath :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in practice with java, but I can offer some guidance to the regular expression, I hope. If you know what the specific attribute and value is that you're looking for, you can use something like the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<tag[45].*attr\s*=\s*[\"']test['\"][^>]*>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<Tag1 attr='test'/><Tag2><Tag4 attr='test'/><Tag5 attr='test'/></Tag2><Tag3 attr='test'/>");

matcher.matches();
```

the regex is made up of the following components:

match the literal string:

followed by either a 4 or a 5 (the [45] designation)

followed by any number of characters preceding the literal string: attr

followed by any number of spaces

followed by the literal character: =

followed by any number of spaces

followed by either the ' or " character

followed by the string literal: test

followed by either the ' or " character

followed by any character that is not >

followed by >

the point in adding some of these extra bits is simply to highlight that you may need/want to consider accounting for different coding styles, etc. note: I took the easy away out by setting the pattern as case-insensitive, but you can omit that and change your expression to check for the appropriate case (for example, if your attribute value is case-sensitive, you can change the 'tag' literal to be [tT][aA][gG] in order to allow matching the tag to be case-insensitive.

I'm apparently too slow to type, since jvataman has already answered your question, but perhaps there is some value in my writeup, so I'll post anyway.